# Provisioning Apache2 w/ Chef-Solo in a Vagrantfile

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I've taken a few aborted stabs at using Vagrant to deploy "local" development instances in the past, but have never been able to take the time to get all the way around the learning curve. I'm trying again and while I can get the Opscode cookbook (apache2) to load, it doesn't work out of the box because the `DocumentRoot` isn't pointing to `/vagrant`.

I get that and it's not unexpected, but I don't have a sense of how to put this all together and the Vagrant documentation, understandably, doesn't go into much detail. The Opscode [cookbook readme](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2), on the other hand, provides so much detail that the noob in me can't wrap my head around it.

Here's the uber simple snippet I have right now:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
  chef.add_recipe "apache2"

  # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
  # chef.json = { :mysql_password => "foo" }
end
```

There's not much there, I know. In some way I know that the `chef.json` component plays into what I want to do, but I don't know how. Can someone provide -- or point me to -- a Vagrant-centric example of how I'd configure the `DocumentRoot` for the Apache2 instance that's being installed? I'm hoping that once I have an example, I'll know how to piece together everything else I need.

Also, just out of curiosity, why am I calling `chef.add_recipe` to load an Apache2 *cookbook*? Or am I misunderstanding the syntax?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `chef.add_recipe "apache2"` says add the default apache2 recipe. It's the same as `chef.add_recipe "apache2::default"`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked that closely at the apache2 cookbook, but I believe that the default-site template which comes with that cookbook points at /var/www  Given this, you have 2 options, I think.  1) use the site resource which comes with the apache2 cookbook to create a new site.  2) mount your web root to /var/www via vagrant.  Which approach kinda depends on your goals.  If you just want to test your web site, I'd recommend 2.  In order to do this,  you'll add something like this to your vagrant config:

```
config.vm.share_folder "web", "/var/www", "~/src/www"
```

where the first argument is an arbitrary id for the share, the second is the target directory (/var/www in this case, since that is what is pointed to in the apache config) and the third is the local path that you are sharing.

N.B. Virtualbox is not great with symlinks, so if there are symlinks in your share, you'll want to add this:

```
config.vm.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/graph", "1"]
```

which will enable symlinks to work.

If you are interested in learning Chef, then you can take approach #1.  This will require creating your own cookbook and write a template which can generate the appropriate configuration file in combination with the apache site definition.   If this is your goal, then I can expand this answer to give you details on how to implement this as well.

HTH.

Comment: Can you please expand the answer to indeed give the details on how to create a new virtual host that will point to the /vagrant share ?